# Unable to access sharepoint lists using python

Tags: python, sharepoint, urllib2

I am using python-sharepoint to access data from my sharepoint account. But I always get a `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error. I am following [this github link](https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint). Here is my code:

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
server_url = 'https://myServerUrl.sharepoint.com/'
site_url = server_url + 'sites/test'
username = 'myUsername.onmicrosoft.com'
password = 'myPassword'

opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url, username, password)
site = SharePointSite(site_url, opener)
for sp_list in site.lists:
    print (sp_list)
```

I also tried creating urllib2 opener as:

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
import urllib2

password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, server_url, username, password)
auth_handler = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(password_manager)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)

site = SharePointSite(site_url, opener)
for sp_list in site.lists:
    print (sp_list)
```

But again it gives same error. Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: what version of SharePoint you're using?

Comment: Right now I am using office 365 sharepoint in trial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither *Basic* nor *NTLM* authentication methods are not supported in SharePoint Online, which makes [python-sharepoint](https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint) not the best choice here.

Instead i would recommend to give a try [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/) which supports Office 365/SharePoint Online.

Here is the similar example for getting all the lists in a site and printing its title

```
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url='https://contoso.sharepoint.com')
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username='jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'],
                                   password='--password--'):

    ctx = ClientContext(settings['url'], ctx_auth)
    lists = ctx.web.lists
    ctx.load(lists)
    ctx.execute_query()
    for l in lists:
        print(l.properties["Title"])
```

Comment: This is a great library. It needs more recognition, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Vadim, I am getting following error, Is there a way to explicity specify verify_ssl=None for a poc ? "Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /GetUserRealm.srf (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))"

Comment: ValueError: Cannot get binary security token for from